# Realm database returning object properties values as null

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

Facing strange issue in Realm:

RealmObject is created based on server response using GSON , stored the same object in Realm using copyToRealmOrUpdate(realmObject). Till this point values of different object attributes are correct.

When i retrieve the vales from Realm i am getting each attribute value as null.

Comment: This is in the FAQ in the official realm documentation https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#android-studio-debugging

Comment: They even included a picture with arrows on it.